Is it possible to find $3\times 3$ matrices such that they can't be factored into 2 different matrices?
It is known that the matrices$$P=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\1&1\end{pmatrix}\quad Q=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$$are prime - i.e., there are no matrices other than the identity matrix such that $LU=P$ or $LU=Q$ where ($\mathcal M_{nm}$ here denotes the set of all $n\times m$ matrices)$$L,U\in\mathcal M_{22}\\a_{ij},b_{ij}\in\mathbb Z_+\quad\forall(i,j)$$ However, I would like to know if there exists $3\times3$ matrices with this property.
I would like to note that I would like to restrict my search to $3\times3$ matrices where $$P\in\mathcal M_{33}\\p_{ij}\in\mathbb Z_+\quad\forall(i,j)$$
Here's my thinking:

Notice that (where $(\cdot)^T$ denotes the transpose of a matrix) we have $P^T=Q$, so therefore if a $3\times3$ matrix satisfies the property of not being able to be factorized into 2 matrices, then its transpose also satisfies the property.
Consider the matrices$$A=\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}&a_{13}\\a_{21}&a_{22}&a_{23}\\a_{31}&a_{32}&a_{33}\end{pmatrix}\\B=\begin{pmatrix}b_{11}&b_{12}&b_{13}\\b_{21}&b_{22}&b_{23}\\b_{31}&b_{32}&b_{33}\end{pmatrix}$$Then our prime $3\times3$ matrix $P$ does not satisfy the equations (because $AB\ne P$)$$a_{11}b_{11}+a_{12}b_{21}+a_{13}b_{31}=p_{11}\\a_{11}b_{12}+a_{12}b_{22}+a_{13}b_{32}=p_{12}\\a_{11}b_{13}+a_{12}b_{23}+a_{13}b_{33}=p_{13}\\a_{21}b_{11}+a_{22}b_{21}+a_{23}b_{31}=p_{21}\\a_{21}b_{12}+a_{22}b_{22}+a_{23}b_{32}=p_{22}\\a_{21}b_{13}+a_{22}b_{23}+a_{23}b_{33}=p_{23}\\a_{31}b_{11}+a_{32}b_{12}+a_{33}b_{13}=p_{31}\\a_{31}b_{12}+a_{32}b_{22}+a_{33}b_{23}=p_{32}\\a_{31}b_{13}+a_{32}b_{23}+a_{33}b_{33}=p_{33}$$and therefore we can notice that if $(AB)^T=B^TA^T=P^T$, then the solution set (where the $c_{ij}$'s and $d_{ij}$'s all correspond to constants that are yet to be determined)$$\begin{bmatrix}a_{11}\\a_{12}\\\vdots\\a_{32}\\a_{33}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}c_{11}\\c_{12}\\\vdots\\c_{32}\\c_{33}\end{bmatrix}\quad\begin{bmatrix}b_{11}\\b_{12}\\\vdots\\b_{32}\\b_{33}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}d_{11}\\d_{12}\\\vdots\\d_{32}\\d_{33}\end{bmatrix}$$also correspond to the solution set for the entries of the matrices $A,B$ in $AB=P$.

But I am stuck on what to do for finding 3x3 "prime" matrices from here, so my question is:

Is there anything I would be able to do from here to find exact entries for "prime" $3\times3$ matrices? If not, what other restrictions would I need to place on these matrices to be able to find them?


@ArturoMagidin No, I'm just stating that $L$ and $U$ are just 3x3 matrices. If this also makes for a necessary restriction, then we could also have $L$ and $U$ be restricted to having nonnegative integer entries along with $P$, so $l_{ij},u_{ij},p_{ij}\in\mathbb Z_+\quad\forall(i,j)$ where $L,U,P\in\mathcal M_{33}$.

@ArturoMagidin Ah sorry about that. I think what I was trying to state there was that given two matrices $A,B\in\mathcal M_{22}$ with $a_{ij},b_{ij}\in\mathbb Z_+\quad\forall(i,j)$, we cannot find entries of $A,B$ (that satisfy the given conditions) such that $AB$ is equal to [[1,0],[1,1]] or [[1,1],[0,1]]. (unless there is something else I'm forgetting to add)

With non-negative entries, you can always conjugate by a nontrivial permutation matrix; e.g., $$\left(\begin{array}{ccc}a&b&c\d&e&f\g&h&i\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{ccc}0&1&0\1&0&0\0&0&1\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{ccc}d&e&f\a&b&c\g&h&i\end{array}\right).$$ If you require strictly positive entries then the identity doesn't occur anyway, but then neither do the matrices you are starting from.
